# How can I write database Django database model instances during startup of the Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Is there a way to write the values of database model instances with initialization values during the startup phase of the Django project?

I'm not interested in migrations which require to invoke the command line prior to starting the Django project. The changes to the database shall be persistent w.r.t. the database change history.

In my case the system is in the IIoT context:

- An edge backend
- a MQTT broker
- potentially several end-device agents.

The operating state of the overall application consists of the operating state of the edge backend, the MQTT broker and the end devices.

The single source of truth about the opstate shall be the database.  This means only the edge backend needs to know about the opstate.

Initially after every start/restart of the Django project the operating state of all sub-components shall be unknown. One database model instance (singleton) holds the operating state of the overall distributed system via one-to-one references.

Comment: What are you trying to write to the database? There are different solutions for different problems. "I'm not interested in migrations which require to invoke the command line prior to starting the Django project."—Why not? This is a valid solution in some use cases. Migrations need to be run anyway to create your schema. "The changes to the database shall be persistent w.r.t. the database change history."—Migrations sound like a pretty good option.

Comment: In my case the db model instance (singleton) holds the operating state of a distributed system. I thought the main use case for migrations is to apply changes to the "database layout" across the lifetime of a Django project and to setup databases for testing. Please prove me wrong if migrations could be suitable in my use case as well.

Comment: And what exactly is "the startup phase of the Django project"? When the project is created? When it is *first* executed? Every time  it is executed? In that case what happens when the project/data changes and there are migrations?

Comment: In that case you should consider no data a state.

Comment: "Startup phase of the Django project" means every time the application is started. Means every start including possible restarts of the Django project. Initially I did not want to use a db model at all. However I need to log changes to the operating state so using a model seemed suitable.

Comment: Migrations can also be a good choice for populating certain types data tables, e.g. if you need a table listing all of the provinces in your country. Those values basically never change and may be necessary for other tables to reference. But now that you've said it's for the operating state of a distributed system, I agree that they're a bad choice. State definitely shouldn't go in migrations.

Comment: Exactly. That's the reason for this question :)

Comment: Right, but you need to tell us enough so it makes sense. See [ask]. In any case, why do you need to do _anything_ when an instance starts up? Without knowing a lot more about your architecture specific recommendations become tricky, but shouldn't all of your instances already be sharing state, e.g. by pointing to the same database?

Comment: You're totally right. In my case the system is in the IIoT context. An edge backend, a MQTT broker and potentially several end device agents. The operating state of the overall application consists of the operating state of the edge backend, the MQTT broker and the end devices. The single source of truth about the opstate shall be database. Initially the operating state of all sub-components shall be unknown. Should be reasonable to add this information to the question...

Comment: @thinwybk, please do.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a fixture?

```sh
django-admin loaddata fixture [fixture ...]
```

or

```py
python manage.py loaddata fixture <file>
```

### Edit:

Ok so you make 2 points:

1. There should be a history logged in the database.
2. Signals should not be triggered.

#### point 1:

Since `loaddata` is using not the model to create the instances and save them, I don't know how it handles the history. Maybe someone else can weigh in here?

#### point 2:

as for signals, this is how you avoid the signals from firing when loading fixtures as explained in the **official django documentation:**

> When fixture files are processed, the data is saved to the database as
>   is. Model defined save() methods are not called, and any pre_save or
>   post_save signals will be called with raw=True since the instance only
>   contains attributes that are local to the model. You may, for example,
>   want to disable handlers that access related fields that aren’t
>   present during fixture loading and would otherwise raise an exception:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import MyModel

def my_handler(**kwargs):
    # disable the handler during fixture loading
    if kwargs['raw']:
        return
    ...

post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=MyModel)
```

- [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)

Comment: Is the change according to fixture preserved to the database history as well? (The change should be available in the database history.) Are signals triggered when fixtures are applied? (Signals should not be triggered by the fixture.)

Comment: @thinwybk check out the edit, it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'll try out tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding point 1: Is the database history before applying the fixture preserved until after it's apllication? Or does the fixture lead to a reset of the history?